# How can you show that $f\delta′=f(0)\delta′−f′(0)\delta$ for a function f that is infinitely differentiable?

Tags: functions, derivatives, physics, distribution-theory, mathematical-physics

Assume that $f$ is infinitely differentiable. Let $\delta$ be the (Dirac) delta functional.

I know that $f\delta = f(0)\delta$, but I'm not sure how to derive the equation  $f\delta′=f(0)\delta′−f′(0)\delta$.

Comment: What is $\delta$? What is $f$? What is the context? Random symbols and equations do not a question make :( Also, put the whole question in the body. Don't spread it between the body and title.

Comment: Define your stuff, please.

Comment: It looks like tempered distributions to me. $f$ is probably a Schwartz function, and $\delta$ a dirac measure.

Comment: I've fixed it up in what I assume is the correct way.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you mean the delta function(al) $\delta(x)$.

If so, you should use formal integration by parts.
$$\int g\times (f\delta') =\int -(fg)'\delta = \int -(f'(0)g(x)+g'(x)f(0))\delta = -f'(0) \int g\delta-f(0)\int g'\delta$$

Integrating the last term by parts and stripping off the $\int g\times$ gives the result.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing an $f$ in the left hand side.

Compute $(f\delta)'$ in two different ways.

On one hand $(f\delta)' = f'\delta + f\delta' = f'(0)\delta + f\delta'$.

On the other hand $(f\delta)' = (f(0)\delta)' = f(0)\delta'$.

Hence $f\delta' = f(0)\delta' - f'(0)\delta$.

Comment: It seems a bit strange to use Leibniz in distribution theory to me; is this commonly done?

Comment: @Sharkos It's a (fairly easy) exercise to show that $(fU)' = fU' + f'U$ for $f \in C^\infty$ and $U \in \mathscr{D}'$.

Comment: Yeah, I realize its equivalence in this context. I wasn't questioning its truth at all, I simply meant I'd never seen anyone choose to use it before. Most authors I've seen have emphasized the fundamental definitions in terms of extending integration rather than pointwise statements.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't think of Leibniz rule *pointwise*, but as an equality of distributions.

Comment: Absolutely, but my point was how suggestive the notation is. Sorry, I'm being unclear. I'm simply saying that it seemed unusual to write it this way, as if there's nothing to prove. It's purely stylistic, not mathematical.

Answer (score 3):

(I suppose that with $\delta$ you mean the Dirac function.)
Just evaluate $(f(t)\delta(t))'$ in two ways.

First, use Leibniz' rule:
$$
(f(t)\delta(t))'=f(t)\delta'(t)+f'(t)\delta(t)=f(t)\delta'(t)+f'(0)\delta(t).
$$
We also have
$$
(f(t)\delta(t))'=(f(0)\delta(t))'=f(0)\delta'(t).
$$

Since the two expressions must be equal, we have
$$
f(t)\delta'(t)=f(0)\delta'(t)-f'(0)\delta(t).
$$

Answer (score 1):

you can also expand $f$ into Taylor series

$f(t)=f(0)+f'(0)t + \frac{f''(0)}{2!}t^2+\cdots$

and consider

$(t \delta(t))' = 0 = \delta(t) + t\delta'(t)$

So we have

$t\delta'(t) =- \delta(t)$

all high order terms involving $t^n \delta'(t)=0, n\ge2$.

Finally

$f\delta′=f(0)\delta′−f′(0)\delta$.